# htaccess only one file in subfolder and keeping the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to put files in a new folder like this:
domain.com/newsite/newpanel/events.php

There are other files in the server like:

- domain.com/events.php,
- domain.com/oldsite/events.php etc.

Requirement 1:
I cannot redirect everything (because old implementations exist) with generic rules,
so I only want to redirect specific urls.
domain.com/events should now skip the old files and go to domain.com/newsite/newpanel/events.php

Requirement 2:
I tried something like this

```
RewriteRule ^events /newsite/newpanel/events/$1 [P]
```

but the url on the url bar will change. Is it possible for it to display domain.com/events?

thank you all!

Comment: Your domain names looks same in samples(front end and backend urls) but you are using flag `[P]` which is for proxy I believe, could you please confirm if you have same domain name for which you need only redirect/rewriting of urls once?

Comment: yes, same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has mentioned different URLs in comments section so adding solution as per that here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/CProjects/events/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ CProjects/folderA/folderB/events [L]
```

---

---

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs after putting these Rules into your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond ^/events/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newsite/newpanel/events.php [L]
```

Comment: nope, didn't work. It says file not found.

Comment: @phantomhive could you please give here sample link which you were hitting and it's not working so that I could check further on this one.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! ok my link is: http://localhost/CProjects/folderA/folderB/events and I want it to be accessible at http://localhost/CProjects/events. It's localhost atm but will get deployed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: also the url bar shouldn't change the display, but it should remain as localhost/CProjects/events.

Comment: @phantomhive, this looks totally different from your initial question I believe :) let me add solution for this one in a min or so.

Comment: @phantomhive, Please check my EDIT solution once and let me know then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225960/discussion-between-phantomhive-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @phantomhive, hey, I am sorry I can't access this link from laptop, could you please comment here itself, thank you